# what is a view engine in react and what is does,as the code conversion is done by babel and webpack

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

I am not getting why we use to define view engine if babel is working as transpiler?So what view engine is doing.is it only telling express that are code file will having the mentioned extension??

Comment: its basically express where we define view engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view engine allows you to use static template files in your application. Declaring what view engine to use when instantiating the Express server allows the developer to write in a template, and then pass in data in an argument to the express render function, and is then parsed into html and then sent over to the client.

I believe for the most part you do not need a view engine for your React application unless you are planning to have your entry file as something other than an html file like an ejs template.